# Is strictly harder than NP-hard cryptography possible?

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity, cryptography, sat

Looks like there is cryptography based on NP-hard problem, e.g. [McEliece cryptosystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McEliece_cryptosystem).  The algorithm is an asymmetric encryption algorithm and is based on the hardness of decoding a general linear code (which is known to be NP-hard)

We are trying to strengthen this result.

> Q1: Is strictly harder than NP-hard cryptography encryption or signature algorithm possible?

We don't allow [One-Time Pads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad) (OTP) and similar external secrets.

> Conjecture J1: the answer is negative via generic attack of
> [symbolic execution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_execution) and then solve SAT with NP-oracle.

J1 implies that if a C language program implements some cryptographic
algorithm and runs in time $X$ milliseconds, then the symbolic execution size of the CNF formula that breaks the algorithm is polynomial in $X$.
XXX make this more rigorous.

It may be a good idea to unroll the loops by hand and ask about loopless
programs.

Counterexample to J1 might be candidate for hard cryptography.

The main problem with J1 is that the resulting CNF might be of exponential
size. We did some experiments with [CBMC: Bounded Model Checker](http://www.cprover.org/cbmc/) with factorization and the hash function SHA256 and the
CNF were small enough.

Here is toy RSA example with zero knowledge of integer factorization:

```
 void main() {
 int nondetint();/* can be anything */
 int p,q,n;
 p=nondetint();
 q=nondetint();
 n=p*q;
 __CPROVER_assert(!(n==13*17 && 1 <p && p <n && 1 < q && q <n),"factor");
 }
 $cbmc --trace factor1.c
```

This approach might be used to mine bitcoins [SAT solving - An alternative to brute force bitcoin mining](http://jheusser.github.io/2013/02/03/satcoin.html).

Also this appears consistent with the fact that if P=NP all crypto will break.

Potential candidates are $\Sigma_2^p$-hard problems.

Comment: Is there existing NP-hard cryptography?

Comment: @Cechco Yes, but the scheme was broken, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle%E2%80%93Hellman_knapsack_cryptosystem

Comment: [McEliece's cryptosystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McEliece_cryptosystem) is based on the hardness of decoding a general linear code, which is NP-hard.  It might not be the most efficient cryptosystem today, but it isn't "broken" in any sense.

Comment: @BenSmith Thanks. Do you have opinion about the conjecture (in case it makes sense)?

Comment: Could you point to a definition of "NP-hard crypto" for the outsiders, please? Also, is there a way of making "we don't allow One Time Pads (OTP) and similar external secrets" less hand-wavy?

Comment: @AndrejBauer Thanks, I edited trying to clarify. Feel free to edit. OTP is unbreakable crypto by definition.

Comment: NP Hard is a lower bound on hardness, not an upper bound. "Harder" than NP Hard implies NP Hard

Comment: Also, a cipher by definition involves an external secret: Namely, the key. In a OTP, the key is necessarily the same size as the message

Comment: Perhaps you mean that the secret is "small" but the message can be reasonably "large"; in which case, a OTP can't work

Comment: @AndrejBauer A [cipher indistinguishability problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciphertext_indistinguishability) for a given cipher is NP-Hard if an oracle that can win the cipher indistinguishability game in polynomial time can also be used to solve an NP-Hard problem in polynomial time

Comment: Take your favourite class of difficult decision problems (say, provably exponential time). Encode a message as a sequence of problem statements, one with FALSE answer for a 0 and one with TRUE answer for a 1.

Comment: I don't have an opinion on the conjecture, I'm not even sure it's well-posed (cf. @ogogmad 's comments).  I'm a bit confused by the inclusion of OTP here, to be honest: with OTP you're looking at information-theoretic security, not algorithmic complexity.

Comment: @BenSmith The conjecture is true and confirmed by Daniel Kröning,
the CBMC author.

Answer (score 9):

I think I may not understand your model of cryptography. My model would be that encryption is a polynomial time computable, injective, function from plaintexts of length $m$ to cipher texts of length $n$, and decryption is inverting this function. In that case, such a problem will always be in NP.

Indeed, we must have $m \leq n$, since we require that encryption be injective. Given a coded message of length $n$, the plaintext is then a witness of length $m \leq n$ that shows that the decoding can be found. So an NP-oracle can always just guess the message, and then check in polynomial time that its guess is correct.

Which aspect of your model am I missing?

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense, you are not missing anything. I though at very abstract level of breaking the underlying math: since there are harder than NP problems, can crypto benefit from this.

Comment: Since the discussion is concerned with asymmetric encryption, shouldn't "polynomial time" have a dependence on key length?

Comment: @S.Carnahan Yes, but the trouble is that now we get into modeling issues. Quite likely, the map (key, message) to cipher text is not invertible. Rather, as a code breaker, my goal is to find a preimage (key, message) where the message is plausible English text. I wanted to make the OP spell out their choices here instead of trying to guess.

Comment: For any model I can think of, decryption is in NP.

Comment: @David E Speyer what is your idea about keyless cryptography such as hash function? In this case the encrypted message is shorter than the message.